# Convert buffer to readable string javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, protocol-buffers, decoding

I receive a JSON as a buffer. I want to parse it into a readable or JSON object.

However, despite all techniques (`JSON.stringify()`, `toString('utf8'`), I am not able to get it done.

here is what I have so far:

[image]

And here is what it gives me:

[image]

How can I transform it into a readable something?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. Please do not post PICTURES of code

Comment: Looks like you need to use fromCharCode on the result

Comment: @mplungjan Code comming from a VM without clipboard sharing capacity.

Comment: The last one seems to be the "readable something". Seems like serialization goes wrong on the other end.

Comment: Lol :))) You need to get to the provider and find out why they send you `[object Object]`


    `console.log(String.fromCharCode(91,111,98,106,101,99,116,32,79,98,106,101,99,116,93))`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code is working. The buffer you have is actually the string `"[object Object]"`.

```
let b = Buffer.from('[object Object]', 'utf8')
console.log(JSON.stringify(b))
// {"type":"Buffer","data":[91,111,98,106,101,99,116,32,79,98,106,101,99,116,93]}

console.log(b.toString('utf8'))
// [Object object]
```

The problem you need to figure out is why is a buffer with that string being sent. It seems like the sender of the buffer needs to call `stringify` or otherwise serialize the object before sending it. Then you can turn it back to a string with `toString()` and use `JSON.parse()` on the string.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
console.log(Buffer.from(val).toString());
```

This will convert `[object Object]` as a string

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with hexadecimal representation of buffers use:

```
Buffer.from(val).toString('hex')
```